# Python Code returns 'NoneType' instead of 'int'

Tags: python, int, nonetype

Sorry, i'm a complete beginner, just started yesterday.

I have an issues with the below code. So, as long as I enter a number, it works fine and it will return as 'int' (that's what I need). But, if I enter anything else that triggers the number_validation() functions again, it will return as 'NoneType'. Any idea why or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for you help!

```
def number_validation():
    number = input("Please enter a number: ")
    if number == "":
        print("You need to enter a number")
        number_validation()
    elif number != "":
        if number.isdigit() == True:
            number = int(number)
            return number
        else:
            print("Numbers only, no spaces, please try again!")
            number_validation()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're not `return`ing `number_validation` when you call it the second time.

```
In [210]: def number_validation():
     ...:     number = input("Please enter a number: ")
     ...:     if number == "":
     ...:         print("You need to enter a number")
     ...:         number_validation()
     ...:     elif number != "":
     ...:         if number.isdigit() == True:
     ...:             number = int(number)
     ...:             return number
     ...:         else:
     ...:             print("Numbers only, no spaces, please try again!")
     ...:             return number_validation()      # Note the return here
     ...:

In [211]: number_validation()
Please enter a number: a
Numbers only, no spaces, please try again!
Please enter a number: 10
Out[211]: 10
```

With your original code, you are reaching the end of the function without returning anything so Python will implicitly return a `None`

Comment: thanks very much for your help!